# Print contents of several arrays in columns sorted by the key in tcl

Tags: arrays, tcl

I have several arrays with same key range. I am trying to print them as columns sorted by key value.

For eg: binA($i), binB($i), binC($i) I:1-100

```
Expected output:
i A B C
1 binA(1) binB(1) binC(1)
2
3
....
100 .....
```

Can anyone please show me how to do this in TCL?

Comment: loop : `for {set i 1} {$i <= 100} {incr i} {...}` ? it helps you ?

Answer (score 0):

untested

```
set bins {A B C}

foreach i [lsort -integer [array names binA]] {
    set fields [list $i]
    foreach bin $bins {
        lappend fields [set bin${bin}($i)]
    }
    puts [join $fields]
}
```